# Messenger and Message use without Handler reference

Tags: java, android, handler, message, messenger

[Messenger constructor:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)

```
Messenger(Handler target)
Create a new Messenger pointing to the given Handler.
```

I would like to send a Message through a Messenger. However, in the place I am sending the Message I do not have a reference to the Handler, only to Messenger which points to the given Handler.

[Message Construcotr:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)

```
static Message   obtain(Handler h, int what, Object obj)
Same as obtain(), but sets the values of the target, what, and obj members.
```

All of the Message.obtain(...params...) methods besides simply Message.obtain() require a Handler be put in.

How do I avoid having to put in a Handler into Message if I already have the  reference to the Handler in Messenger?

Comment: so who and how creates the Messenger?

Comment: I am starting an activity with startActivity(intent). Since Handler can't be put into Extras, I have to use Messenger. So I am making a messenger with the handler reference, intent.putExtra(messenger) and retrieving it on the 'other side'.

Comment: tried Message.obtain(null, what)? Messenger doesnt use Message.target field so it seems it can be null

Comment: Thank you for testing it! That is good news! (I would try it but my code is so jumbled right now from having to re-write a lot of it). If you put up an answer I will mark it as correct!